# Please provide your method of laying out and resizing `JPanel`s in a frame

Tags: java, swing, containers, panel, frame

[Panel Alignment Practice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEYMa.jpg)

Panel alignment practice. Each panel is a color. I haven't been able to resize using `new Dimension()` or flexibly manipulate the panels. I've tried `frm.setLayout(null)` with `setBounds()` and `GridBagConstraints`.

```
   frm = new JFrame();

   frmLayout = new BorderLayout();
   frmLayout.layoutContainer(frm.getContentPane());


   mainPnl = new MainPanel();
   sP = new SecondPanel();
   tP = new ThirdPanel();

   getContentPane().add(mainPnl, BorderLayout.WEST);
   getContentPane().add(sP, BorderLayout.EAST);
   getContentPane().add(tP, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: When using the BorderLayout (which is the default layout for a JFrame, the components will automatically resize. So know each of your child panels (mainPnl, sP and tP) need to use appropriate layout manager that will allow components to resize. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples to get you started. The panels in your example will automatically resize as you add components to them.

Comment: @camickr "The panels in your example will automatically resize as you add components to them." I had a feeling that was the case. I was just hoping there was a way to move the panels around as like a pre-arranging to plan components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the LayoutManager of a JPanel use :

```
frm.getContentPane().setLayout(frmLayout);
```

Don’t set it to null, a null-layout isn’t resized with the JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

[I was able to arrange the panels.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGIJk.jpg)

It seems if I add panels to a main panel `setBounds()` works. I'm probably violating all of your favorite swing conventions but hey, I'll learn just like you all at some point. Only issue with `setBounds()` so far is resizing the window. `getWidth()` or `getHeight()` cause the panel to disappear.

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

SecondPanel sP;
ThirdPanel tP;
FourthPanel fP;

public MainPanel()
{

  setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
  setLayout(null);
  sP = new SecondPanel();
  sP.setBounds(0, 0, 90, 90);
  tP = new ThirdPanel();
  tP.setBounds(90, 0, 410, 90);
  fP = new FourthPanel();
  fP.setBounds(0, 400, 500, 100);

  add(sP);
  add(tP);
  add(fP);

}
```

}

Comment: `I'll learn just like you all at some point.` - the time to learn is now. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers (for too many reasons to list here). You should NOT be hardcoding numbers. With your code if you ever change the size of one component if will affect the location of another. This is a maintenance disaster. It is the job of the layout manager to set the size/location of the component automatically for you..

Comment: @camickr I can agree with that, I guess I'm just not experienced enough to feel the flexibility of any of the layout managers.

Comment: `I'm just not experienced enough to feel the flexibility` - the only way you get experience with anything in life is to do it. You don't gain experience by avoiding it. That is the benefit of a forums. You have a specific requirement you try to solve. If you have a problem then you ask a detailed question stating the requirement and generally somebody will be able to help you solve the problem. The real question with your code above, is why are some components 90 another 410 and another 500? Think of your web page. The size of components change as you change the size of the frame.

Comment: You need to think more about the usage of the frame and less about the individual pixels. You need to think about when the frame size changes, which component or components change?

Comment: @camickr I completely agree. Thank you for the kick in the @$$ .. This particular gui was just to see if I could move panels around, not to actually make anything. I'm now utilizing the default `BorderLayout`. However, I've now run into the issue that you cannot retrieve a panel's size parameters `(width, height)`, to store them in a variable, and pass them as a `width` or `height` parameter for another method. I'm only seeing `Listeners` as a solution but I have the feeling there is something easier. Thanks for your help, for real.